# Route not recognized in rails3 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I was tinkering with this a few days ago and it seemed to be working.  But now I went back to this application setup and I can't seem to get to the home page with

```
http://localhost:3000
```

Here is my routes.rb configuration

```
  devise_for :users

  resources :home
  get "home/index"

  resources :formats
  get "formats/index" #display all formats

root :to => "home#index"
```

Any idea why I am getting the error that the route is not recognized?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When having routing problems, always check the output of `rake routes` to be sure it's listed correctly. Generally the correct way to route the `/` path is using the `root` method as you've done there.

The second thing to check is that you're connecting to the correct application. You may have more than one instance of `rails server` running on different ports.

Make sure that you're seeing updates to `log/development.log` when you make your request.